# How to open lightbox image on body load

Tags: jquery, lightbox, pageload

I am using lightbox by Warren Krewenki

https://github.com/krewenki/jquery-lightbox

Is there a way to open an image on page load? Like if there is some jQuery trigger which I can call on page load which will emulate like user clicking on image and then it will open lightbox?

Or if this is not possible then any other plugin that will allow me to open and HTML page in lightbox? I remember I saw one here but forgot the link.

Comment: Have you tried `$(function(){ $('#selector').click(); });`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger a click on one of the links to which lightbox is attached:

```
$(function () {
    $('a.lightbox').lightbox();
    $('a.lightbox:first').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect. Just need to ask one thing, let's say I have two images on page. Using the above code it opens the first image. What if I want to open second one? I tried 'a.lightbox:second' but it didn't work.

Comment: You can use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) operator like `a.lightbox:eq(1)` (numbering starts from zero).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#myLightbox').show();
});
```

You can try this one also :-

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/